# Change column header in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

This is my table right now :

[image]

This is the code that I can change the column title:

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setHeaderValue("Lecturersssss");
```

But the column title would not change until I hover the mouse on the `Lecturer` column header.

Even when i use `table.repaint()` after this code, it won't change.
Do you guys have any idea how can I solve this issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a `MouseEvent` to do this?

Comment: no, i have that code inside an actionlistener of a button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
JTableHeader header= table.getTableHeader();
TableColumnModel colMod = header.getColumnModel();
TableColumn tabCol = colMod.getColumn(0);
tabCol.setHeaderValue("Lecturersssss");
header.repaint();
```

Comment: This should work. It is probably not even necessary to repaint.

Comment: i still have the same issue

Comment: i have a messy code: http://pastebin.com/phFGAaXV i don't know whether it can helps or not

Answer (score 2):

Chalita's suggestion **should** work. Here's sanity check short demonstration program. Click the button to change the column header text. Works on my environment at least...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TTT extends JFrame {
    JTable t;
    public TTT() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Object[] cols= new Object[]{"Col1","Col2","Col3"};
        Object[][] vals= new Object[][]{{5,6,7}};
        t = new JTable(vals,cols);
        add(new JScrollPane(t),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JButton b = new JButton("Change Column Header");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Random r = new Random();
                Enumeration<TableColumn> e = t.getColumnModel().getColumns();
                while( e.hasMoreElements( ) )
                    e.nextElement().setHeaderValue("Col"+Math.abs(r.nextInt()));
                t.getTableHeader().repaint();
            }
        });
        b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1,25));
        add(b,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setSize(500,150);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TTT().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your example, instead of table.getTableHeader().repaint(); i've been used table.repaint(); problem solved

Comment: under jdk 8 thet table.repaint() doesn't change anything. sigh... :'(

Comment: @gumuruh I would expect this to work also in JDK8, perhaps a new question is in order?